# Use np.savetxt to save the array as a column of csv

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array as:

```
new_data_smooth = [1,2,3,....,2800]
```

I use this code to save the array:

```
with open("label.csv", "w+") as f:
    np.savetxt(f,(new_data_smooth),delimiter=',', fmt='%3f',comments='')
```

which I want to save to a .csv file such that the file looks like:

EX:

```
1,2,3,....,2800
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ptO.jpg

but it gave me this:

EX:

```
1
2
3
...
2800
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gV5q.jpg

Is there a way to save only one row using np.savetxt?

Comment: have you tryed adding a newline='', to savetxt

Comment: write `new_data_smooth[:,None]`, a (n,1) shape

Answer (score 0):

You could add the two lists to create one and write that to disk

```
np.savetxt(f,new_data_smooth+new_data,delimiter=',', fmt='%3f',comments='')
```

or use the newline parameter:

```
np.savetxt(f,(new_data_smooth,new_data),delimiter=',', fmt='%3f',comments='',newline=',')
```

But with the newline parameter you would end up with a comma at the end of the file

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Sorry, neither are working, so I rewrite the code a little bit

`np.savetxt(f,new_data_smooth,delimiter=',', fmt='%3f',comments='',newline = '\t')`


It is stored in row format, but becomes one column
https://imgur.com/u4KmaMU

What I want is a column corresponding to one value.

Comment: Its hard to guess what you want, please give a desired result in your question. Why new_data_smooth and new_data in the question?

Comment: Sorry for not expressing it completely, the result I want is as follows,https://imgur.com/a/zYiHV4P
So I use this code,
`np.savetxt(f,new_data_smooth1,delimiter=',', fmt='%.3f',comments='')`
I get this result.
https://imgur.com/MnD6TJx
Forget new_data_smooth and new_data.